# return issues in java

Tags: java, return, conditional-statements

So I'm writing a mersense script for codeeval in java to  get some practice with the language (I'm fairly new to it). At one point I'm checking if the number is prime and in my method I do the normal checks and everything looks great

```
public static boolean isPrime (int testValue){
  if (testValue < 4){
    return true;
  } else if (testValue % 2 == 0){
    return false; 
  } else {
    for (int I = 1; I < Math.sqrt (testValue); I++){
      if (testValue % I == 0 ){
         return false; 
     }
   }
   return true;
  }
}
```

however the only things getting through seem to be 1 and 3. Can I not do that return after the for loop is that what's wrong? Any ideas?

Edit:

Here is the full code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Main{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    int n;
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int candidate;
    while((line = buffer.readLine()) != null){
        n = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            candidate = mersenne(i);
            if(isPrime(candidate)){
                System.out.println(candidate + " "+ isPrime(candidate));
                if((i+1) >= n){
                    result.append(candidate);
                }else{
                    result.append(candidate + ", ");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(result.toString());
        result = new StringBuilder();
    }
}

public static int mersenne (int testValue){
    return (int)Math.pow(2,testValue) - 1;
}
public static boolean isPrime(int testValue){
    if(testValue < 4 && testValue > 1){
        return true;
    }else if(testValue % 2 == 0){
        return false;
    }else{
        for(int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(testValue); i++){
            if(testValue % i == 0){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the only things getting through"? As in, `n` above 3 returns false for `isPrime(n)`?

Comment: `testValue % 1 == 0` is always true. This is the sort of bug which is easily found using your debugger.

Comment: aside: by convention, you typically use lower case for `i` in your `for` loop

Comment: You could also make the code a bit cleaner by getting rid of all the `elses`.  When an if statement block always ends with a `return`, control immediately returns to the calling code and nothing after that will be executed (excepting a `finally` block).  So the `else` is unnecessary, it just makes the code harder to read (especially without proper indenting).

Comment: @discipline yes it seems that way the only output I am getting for any input is 1,3, also i added the entire class if that helps

Comment: @MarkOlsson do you mean like a bunch of if statements sans else like

    if(x){
       return x;
    }
    if(y){
      return y;
    }
    if(z){
      return z;
    }

Comment: @bphilipnyc when i first made the post I was on my cell phone and it would not let me use a lower case i

Comment: @tourn171 - Exactly.  It makes the code a lot easier to read, though it probably isn't any more or less efficient.  Some people will also tell you there should only be one return statement as well because it can be hard to debug or modify, but can often be less efficient, so it's a matter of opinion.  Single return "top-down programming" is pretty old-school and exception try/catch/finally blew that out of the water anyway.

Answer (score 6):

You're starting the loop at 1.  Everything % 1 is 0.  Start at 3.

Comment: .. and increment by 2, you don't need to check the even numbers. also it should be `i <= Math.sqrt(testValue)`

Comment: You do need to start at 3 for multiples of 3.

Comment: You're right, I was looking at the wrong var.  The < 4 bit threw me.

Comment: Yes I should start at 3 and good call from @PeterLawrey I forgot to increment over the even numbers still doesn't explain why any numbers higher than 3 seem to not pass though which is driving me bonkers.

Comment: @tourn171 The answer already explains this. 5 % 1 == 0, 6 % 1 == 0, 7 % 1 == 0, 8 % 1 == 0 etc.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yeah I get what your saying now. How the hell did I miss that before.

Answer (score 2):

your code in the else block:

```
for (int I = 1; I < Math.sqrt (testValue); I++){
      if (testValue % I == 0 ){
         return false; 
     }
   }
```

you should start with I=3:

```
for (int I = 3; I < Math.sqrt (testValue); I++)
```

Since every number % 1 equals to 0 so false will be returned.

Comment: Yeah that was pointed out to me higher up. Kinda feel stupid that I missed that.